# Wordpress links function

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode

Is it possible to display a list with ALL links except of 1 category?

Because I want a page that lists only "Cat1 links", and another page that lists "All links except Cat1".

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories

You can use 'exclude' parameter to exclude categories. Is this what you are looking for ??

Thanks.